# How to get a terms and posts associated with another term?

Tags: custom-taxonomy, templates, taxonomy, archives, terms

The wording of the title is terrible, but I am not sure how else to word it. I have two taxonomies: `product_categories` and `brands`.

I'm on the page `/product-categories/grocery`. So the term here is "Grocery". Posts are tagged with both taxonomies. I am trying to output all of the Brands and posts associated with the term "Grocery".

I'm currently editing `taxonomy-product_categories.php`. This is what I want the page to look like for the above url.

Grocery
Brand A
- Product 1
- Product 2
Brand B
- Product 1
- Product 2

etc.

But right now, the issue with my code, is that I'm getting all Brands, I am unsure how to make it relate specifically to the term page that I'm on, and in this example that's Grocery.

This is my code:

```
$taxonomy = 'brands';
$categories = get_categories( array(
    'taxonomy'          => $taxonomy,
    'hide_empty'        => true,
));

foreach ($categories as $category) :

    $title = $category->name;
    $link = get_category_link($category->cat_ID);

    echo '<h4><a href="' . $link . '">' . $title . '</a></h4>';

    $tax_query = array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => $taxonomy,
            'field'    => 'slug',
            'terms'    => $category,
            'operator' => 'IN',
        )
    );

    // global $post;
    $args = array(
        'post_type'   =>  'products',
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'orderby' => 'title',
        'order' => 'asc',
        'tax_query'   => $tax_query
    );

    $products = new WP_Query( $args );

    if ( $products->have_posts() ) :
    echo '<div class="tax-products">';

        echo '<div class="tax-product-item x-column x-sm x-1-4">';

        while ($products->have_posts()) : $products->the_post();
        // $products = get_posts($args);

        // foreach ( $products as $post ) : setup_postdata( $post );

            //Vars
            $product_title = get_the_title();
            $product_link = get_the_permalink();

            echo '<li class="all-brand-product-item"><a href="' . $product_link . '">' . $product_title . '</a></li>';

        // endforeach; 

        // wp_reset_postdata();
        endwhile;

        echo '</div>'; // end tax-product-item

    echo '</div>'; // end tax-products
    else :
        echo "No Products Found.";
    endif;

    wp_reset_postdata();

endforeach;
```

I feel like somehow if the `get_categories` array could somehow get the `term_id` then maybe it would work the way I need it to.

Comment: How do you know which 'brands' are associated with 'groceries'? Are you trying to control just the list of terms in the menu? Or are you trying to do a full taxonomy intersection of the posts that are being displayed?

Comment: That's the problem, I don't know how to show that 'brands' are associated with 'groceries', that's the missing piece to making this work.